# What is a topological quantum field theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, topological-field-theory

I've seen reasonably tangible explanations of lots of "topological things" in physics like topological spin liquids, the surface code and the Kitaev chain. Although calculations in quantum field theories get pretty complicated, I at least have a rough understanding of what they are in many settings. But I've never seen a concrete explanation of what a [topological quantum field theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_quantum_field_theory) (TQFT) is, and therefore don't understand even the most basic details like what their degrees of freedom are.

For the above examples, concrete toy models are often extremely helpful for understanding more complex analogs. I have heard that TQFTs are often exactly solvable, which gives me hope of finding one that I could solve.

What is a minimal but non-trivial toy model of a topological quantum field theory? Ideally it is mathematically simple enough to explain to an undergraduate. Barring that, hopefully it can at least be precisely connected to more elementary systems that can be understood with less background (I would consider surface codes and spin liquids to count, because many of their essential properties can be explained both visually and unambiguously just by writing down some simple operators acting on qubits).

Comment: Basically, a QFT on spacetime is topological when the correlators are independent of the metric. The simplest examples are 2d TQFTs. There is a formal exposition of these in Kocks book *2d TQFT*. However, these are too simple to describe the 2d TQFTs of interest in physics: the A & B model in string theory.  These 2d TQFTs are what are called extended or local TQFTs. Basically, by making the string topological with what is called the 'topological twist', path integrals can be calculated and these are encoded in what are called the Gromov-Witten invariants. They encode scatrering amplitudes ...

Comment: ... of strings and hence gravitons.

Comment: Chern-Simons theory, discussed in many intro QFT books

Comment: The other main one to mention is BF theory.